# Changing -webkit-mask-position through javascript

Tags: javascript, css, mask, css-mask

I'm working on an iPad webview project that requires a slider to move back and forth over two pictures, revealing one or the other when sliding to the left or right. Due to project restraints, I can't utilize jQuery. I currently have the left picture on top with a transparent mask over it and when the -webkit-mask-position is increased, it reveals more of the bottom picture, when decreased, more of the top (covering the bottom one).

I'm using a javascript plugin called Draggy (https://github.com/jofan/Draggy) to move the slider back and forth and want to use its onChange function call to update the position of the mask, but I can't figure out what javascript calls "-webkit-mask-position" to save my life.

Any ideas?

PS: webkitMaskPosition adds style="-webkit-mask: XX" to the element, which I COULD use (filling in the other values in the js), but it's being really buggy. I'm looking into it now.

OH MAN I GOT IT.

```
var maskSlider = document.getElementById('molecule');
function moveMask(x, y) {
    var xx = x - 285;
    var z = "-webkit-gradient(linear, left center, right center, color-stop(0.5, black), color-stop(0.5, transparent)) no-repeat scroll " + xx + "px padding padding";
    maskSlider.style.webkitMask = z;
}
```

The -285 is to get it to line up to where the slider is on the image. I have no idea if I'm really doing this the right way, but it worked. If anyone can think of a better/ more efficient way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: element.style.webkitMaskPosition ?

Comment: Sorry, meant to address that option. See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently worked a lot about webkit masks which are using CSS3 gradients to make transitions between images.
I preferred to append a `style` tag to `head` tag which is made dynamically by my calculations. And also I used CSS3 animation too. Something like this:

```
 var cssStr = '<style id="myTransition">.myTransition_wipe{' +
                '-webkit-mask-size: 200% 200%;' +
                '-webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;' +
                '-webkit-animation: wipe 2s;' +
                '-webkit-animation-direction: normal;' +
                '-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;' +
                '-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;' +
                '-webkit-mask-position: offsetLeftS 0;' +
                '-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, ' +
                'color-stop(0%, transparent), color-stop(20%, transparent), ' +
                'color-stop(25%, transparent), color-stop(30%, transparent), ' +
                'color-stop(50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(98%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), ' +
                'color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)));}' +
                '@-webkit-keyframes wipe {' +
                '0% { -webkit-mask-position: offsetLeftS 0; }' +
                '100% { -webkit-mask-position: offsetLeftD 0; }' +
                '}' +
                '</style>';
            var compStyle = getComputedStyle(currentElement);
            var width = parseInt(compStyle.getPropertyValue("width"));
            var height = parseInt(compStyle.getPropertyValue("height"));
            cssStr = cssStr.replace(/offsetLeftS/g, '-' + (width * 1) + 'px');
            cssStr = cssStr.replace(/offsetLeftD/g, '+' + (width * 1) + 'px');

            $('head').append(cssStr);
```

When I want to apply a transition, I remove the `style` tag by its ID and remove the class `myTransition_wipe` from element too, then append a new one to `head` tag and add the class name to element too.

**Pay Attention:** You must store the styles that element should have after the animation is finished and add them right after the animation is finished. Otherwise, when you remove class name and style tag, everything will be reset.

Good Luck

Comment: Woah, just saw your post. Thank you, I was actually able to go back and update a few things to make it work even better! Cheers! :)